# leaflet markers from acf field values

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, leaflet, advanced-custom-fields

I like Leaflet so far as it is much easier to include and change the looks than Google Maps. I am using ACF plugin on my Wordpress website where there are several posts with locations in them.
Now what I did is use div attributes to pass data from the php to the JS like this:

```html
<div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>" data-title="<?php echo $title; ?>" data-url="<?php echo $link; ?>" data-category="<?php echo $typ; ?>"></div>
```

this data is then passed into the Leaflet map markup:

```js
// for rendering the Leaflet Map
(function ($) { 
  $(window).load(function () {
    var map = L.map('mapwrap').setView([51.51, 9.19], 5);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, ' +
        '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery &copy; <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
      id: 'mapbox.light',
      //layers: [ group ],
    }).addTo( map );    

    $('.marker').each(function() {
      var lat = $(this).attr('data-lat');
      var lng = $(this).attr('data-lng');
      var name = $(this).attr('data-title');
      var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
      var typ = $(this).attr('data-category');
      var marker = new L.marker([ lat, lng ]).bindPopup( name ).addTo( map );
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

It works good so far as all the markers appear on the map. However now I am trying to reset the map, so that all markers are shown and on a later stage they should be clustered. All examples that I found loop through the markers with a "for" loop, but I couldn't get it to work correctly, so that all the data is passed between my php and the script... I am not that good with jQuery or JS, so please bear with me.

So here are my questions:

1. Is there a better way to loop through each marker found on the page based on the "marker" class? I am using the same function to echo the marker divs for a single post and also for user queries or archive queries.
2. How can I correctly resize the map after all markers are placed?
3. What is the best way of adding a category (var typ) based icon to each marker (currently there are two choices)?

Thanks in advance

## Edit 1:

I played a little along with different ways of storing the data from the loop, as I need it in an array to group the markers. So this is what I came up with:

```
var LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
  options: {
    iconSize:     [43, 57],
    iconAnchor:   [21, 57],
    popupAnchor:  [0, -43],
  }
});

var marker = [];
$.each($('.marker'), function () {
  var lat = $(this).attr('data-lat');
  var lng = $(this).attr('data-lng');
  var name = $(this).attr('data-title');
  var link = $(this).attr('data-url');
  var icon = $(this).attr('data-icon');
  marker = [ name, lat, lng, icon, link ];
  console.log( marker );
});

var markers = [ marker ];

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  var myIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: markers[i][3] });
  marker = new L.marker([markers[i][1],markers[i][2]], {icon: myIcon })
      .bindPopup(markers[i][0])
      .addTo(map);
}
```

This way all my markers with their respective icons (category related icons) are added into the "markers" array.
Still have to test it further, but it seems to work.